# get each value of the same data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameter-passing, custom-data-attribute

I need to get the value in each data-attribute and assign that value to a variable and then I want to pass that variable as an argument in a function (I didn't write the function or the html but have to use it). The data-attribute value is dynamically generated based on the row and column of the table from a different function.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
priceIndex = $(this).attr("data-priceIndex");
```

> *`$(this)` is the parent tableCell.*

And then pass the `priceIndex` variable to the function i.e.

```
<tr><td class="tblProduct selectProduct" data-priceIndex="0_0">
    <div class="priceArea" data-priceIndex="0_0">
        <button class="okButton origProduct" onclick="goToCart(priceIndex, '', true, false)"></button>
    </div>
</td>
<td class="tblProduct selectProduct" data-priceIndex="0_1">
    <div class="priceArea" data-priceIndex="0_1">
        <button class="upgradeButton upgrdProduct" onclick="goToCart(priceIndex, '', false, false)"></button>
    </div>
</td></tr>
```

But that gives me the same value for all `data-priceIndex`.  Why is that happening?  How can I get the value of each data-attributes?  Please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to correct.  Thanks.

.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know what you expect but i think you should rather omit the parameter and retrieve the value in the goToCart function or "wrap" it, the way you try `priceIndex` will always have the same value no matter what button you click:

```
<button class="upgradeButton upgrdProduct" onclick="goToCartWrap('',true,false)"></button>
```

and the function:

```
function goToCartWrap(s,b1,b2){
 priceIndex = $(this).parent().attr("data-priceIndex");
 goToCart(priceIndex, s, b1, b2)
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting as I have to pass the other arguments as well to get their values (not hard-code values). I'm going to try this.